# I am trying to create Azure Data Factory and getting error: RequestDisallowedByPolicy

Tags: azure-data-factory, sandbox, azure-policy

The error that I found is:

```
{
  "code": "InvalidTemplateDeployment",
  "details": [
    {
      "code": "RequestDisallowedByPolicy",
      "target": "adeebadflearning",
      "message": "Resource 'adeebadflearning' was disallowed by policy. Policy identifiers: '[{\"policyAssignment\":{\"name\":\"sqlserver\",\"id\":\"/providers/Microsoft.Management/managementGroups/triplecrown1/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/policyAssignments/4d7e23dc76164960b2c974ac\"},\"policyDefinition\":{\"name\":\"Allowed resource types\",\"id\":\"/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/policyDefinitions/a08ec900-254a-4555-9bf5-e42af04b5c5c\"},\"policySetDefinition\":{\"name\":\"sqlserver\",\"id\":\"/providers/Microsoft.Management/managementGroups/triplecrown1/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/policySetDefinitions/d5a5d5bb-91e0-4a17-9894-25d0f73aa09f\"}}]'.",
      "additionalInfo": [
        {
          "type": "PolicyViolation",
          "info": {
            "policyDefinitionDisplayName": "Allowed resource types",
            "policySetDefinitionDisplayName": "sqlserver",
            "evaluationDetails": {
              "evaluatedExpressions": [
                {
                  "result": "False",
                  "expressionKind": "Field",
                  "expression": "type",
                  "path": "type",
                  "expressionValue": "Microsoft.DataFactory/factories",
                  "targetValue": [
                    "microsoft.resources/resourcegroups",
                    "microsoft.storage/storageaccounts",
                    "microsoft.dbforpostgresql/servers",
                    "microsoft.sql/servers",
                    "microsoft.sql/servers/databases",
                    "microsoft.documentdb/databaseaccounts",
                    "microsoft.sql/servers/elasticpools",
                    "microsoft.dbformysql/servers",
                    "microsoft.operationalinsights/workspaces",
                    "microsoft.operationsmanagement/solutions",
                    "microsoft.insights/actiongroups",
                    "microsoft.insights/activitylogalerts",
                    "microsoft.insights/autoscalesettings",
                    "microsoft.insights/metricalerts"
                  ],
                  "operator": "In"
                }
              ]
            },
            "policyDefinitionId": "/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/policyDefinitions/a08ec900-254a-4555-9bf5-e42af04b5c5c",
            "policySetDefinitionId": "/providers/Microsoft.Management/managementGroups/triplecrown1/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/policySetDefinitions/d5a5d5bb-91e0-4a17-9894-25d0f73aa09f",
            "policyDefinitionReferenceId": "11619501722087078793",
            "policySetDefinitionName": "d5a5d5bb-91e0-4a17-9894-25d0f73aa09f",
            "policyDefinitionName": "a08ec900-254a-4555-9bf5-e42af04b5c5c",
            "policyDefinitionEffect": "deny",
            "policyAssignmentId": "/providers/Microsoft.Management/managementGroups/triplecrown1/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/policyAssignments/4d7e23dc76164960b2c974ac",
            "policyAssignmentName": "4d7e23dc76164960b2c974ac",
            "policyAssignmentDisplayName": "sqlserver",
            "policyAssignmentScope": "/providers/Microsoft.Management/managementGroups/triplecrown1",
            "policyAssignmentParameters": {}
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "message": "The template deployment failed because of policy violation. Please see details for more information."
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This means that there was a policy set for your resource which blocked the deployment, various policies are set for a project for security reasons, you can check which policy blocked your deployment using below PowerShell query:

```
(Get-AzPolicyDefinition -Id "/subscriptions/{guid}/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/policyDefinitions/regionPolicyDefinition").Properties.policyRule | ConvertTo-Json
```

For security or compliance, your subscription administrators might assign policies that limit how resources are deployed. For example, your subscription might have a policy that prevents creating Public IP addresses, Network Security Groups, User-Defined Routes, or route tables. The error message in the Symptoms section shows the name of the policy. To resolve this problem, review the resource policies, and determine how to deploy resources that comply with those policies.

Comment: Hi @A Ahmad : If my response helped you, can you please mark it as an answer so that we can have others from community to benefit from it :). Thanks !